# Is there any solution for HDMI sound with virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hdmi

I used to use virtualbox on windows 7 with no problem,but recently i added HDMI graphic card but when i boot to windows xp sp3 from virtualbox there is no sound.....so does virtualbox support HDMI or not?

My virtual windows xp settings in virtualbox is audio enabled but when i run windows xp from virtualbox and go to device manager there is yellow question mark on audio driver,should i install audio driver inside guest O.S. ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Audio enabled in your VirtualBox settings for the VM that Windows runs in.  The "Windows DirectSound" driver should suffice as long as your host system has audio working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue.

- I have three sound devices on my system, Intel HD sound on the motherboard, AC 97 add on module, and Nvidia HDMI from the Nvidia graphics card.
- I have sound enabled in Virtual Box, and I see three devices in Virtual Box, Intel Sound, Ac 97 and Soundblaster 16.
  And so I assume, not tested yet, that my motherboard sound and Ac 97 will work.

> HDMI sound does not work because that device is not available in the Virtual Box sound device option menu. (tested) I also tried the PCI attach feature that allows you to attach a PCI device to Virtual Box, but I get a message that my chipset is not supported.

- I have three computers connected to the same monitor through a HDMI switch and so I have standardized on HDMI sound, which works great with the exception of Virtual Box.
- I have also vmware installed and HDMI sound is supported by vmware but vmware does not actively support their kernel modules with upcoming kernels, although there are always patches to be found from users which work.

I thought from what I read on the net that Virtual box would be slower compared to vmware but that does not appear to be so on my system and so Virtual Box is a serious and free candidate to vmware.
I hope the HDMI sound issue can be fixed, and in the meantime I will probably use a second set of speakers for it until this issue gets resolved.
I hope this help in someway.

Comment: Where are you seeing three sound devices: in the Virtual Box GUI or inside the VM ?